# How to separate an integer into digits

Tags: excel, vba

In EXCEL VBA how do I separate an integer into individual digits which can then be operated on mathematically, e.g. the integer 123456789 separated into 1,2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 then (1*8), (2*16), (3*32), etc; the 1*8, 2*16, 3*32 are just examples, the actual multipliers could be different e.g. 1*1024, 2*2048, etc. The initial integer (123456789) is a variable (id) from another module within a VBA project. apologies if I didn't explain clearly. Sorry about the formatting (this is my first post on stackoverflow).

```
Option Explicit
Sub NUMalpha()

Private Property Get num() As Integer
    NUMlong = Int(id)
End Property

Dim Digit_1 As Integer

Dim Digit_2 As Integer

Dim Digit_3 As Integer

Dim Digit_4 As Integer

Dim Digit_5 As Integer

Dim Digit_6 As Integer

Dim Digit_7 As Integer

Dim Digit_8 As Integer

Dim Digit_9 As Integer

Digit_1 = left(NUMlong, 1)

Digit_2 = Mid(NUMlong, 2, 1)

Digit_3 = Mid(NUMlong, 3, 1)

Digit_4 = Mid(NUMlong, 4, 1)

Digit_5 = Mid(NUMlong, 5, 1)

Digit_6 = Mid(NUMlong, 6, 1)

Digit_7 = Mid(NUMlong, 7, 1)

Digit_8 = Mid(NUMlong, 8, 1)

Digit_9 = right(NUMlong, 1)

End Property

End Sub
```

Comment: find the length or your string.  Then do a for loop from 1 to length of string reading 1 character at a time using the mid function.  use the loop to position which character you are reading.  You can then either assign the individual characters to a variable to do your math manipulations or you can do you math manipulations inside the loop and keep a running total of the results.  It will really depend on what the math is.

Comment: Hi Dave. It's not clear to me where you're getting 1*8 2*16, etc. Please try explaining this more clearly.

Comment: What coding have you tried so far?

Comment: So far, I have tried:

Answer (score 0):

## VBA solution

```
Sub test()
    Dim sNum As string, i As Long, mulitp As Variant, aryNum As Variant

    sNum = Format(Range("A1").Value, "0")
    mulitp = 8
    ReDim aryNum(1 To Len(sNum)) As Variant

    For i = 1 To Len(sNum)
        aryNum(i) = Mid(sNum, i, 1) * mulitp * 2 ^ (i - 1)
    Next i

    MsgBox Application.Sum(aryNum)
End Sub
```

## Worksheet Formula Solution

Use the formula below
`=SUMPRODUCT(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)*1,8*2^(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))-1))`

This is not a array formula, so press <kbd>enter</kbd>, not <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

123456789 is larger than the maximum Integer size (–32,768 to 32,767) value in VBA.

```
Sub SplitLong()

    Dim digits() As Long
    Dim intValue As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strValue As String

    intValue = 123456789
    strValue = intValue

    ReDim digits(Len(strValue) - 1) As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(strValue)
        digits(i - 1) = Mid$(strValue, i, 1)
    Next

End Sub
```